# Prevent pushing into a wrong remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I want to have two branches locally (e.g. `a-local` and `b-local`) and two branches remotely (e.g. `a-remote`, `b-remote`), and they match in pairs (e.g. `a-local` - `a-remote`, etc). How do I make sure I don't accidentally push a local branch to a wrong remote branch (e.g. `a-local` -> `b-remote`)?

I'm using git 1.8.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Before actually pushing do add a `-n` to the command.  This shows which local branch(s) will be pushed to which remote and remote branch(s) without actually doing the push.  Then you can revise the command, still using `-n` and finally when happy, remove the `-n`.

One thing that I have done is configure the global option of push.default to upstream by `git config --global push.default upstream`.  The default value is matching, which will attempt to push each matching branch.

If your remote is known as `origin` (probably is) the command to push changes on a-local would be `git push origin a-local:a-remote -n`.  But a simple `git push -n` might function based on push.default and upstream configuration (see kirelagin's note).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it's hard to do this *accidentally*.

Once you do `git push --set-upstream origin a-local:a-remote` to make it tracking (and the same for the other pair), you can push with just `git checkout a-local; git push` or `git-push a-local` and I should say you'll have to try hard to accidentally push to a wrong branch…

Comment: It's really not hard. When jumping around between master and some feature branch an accidental `push origin feature` while in master is quite possible.